# Not able to set state in class component , Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-class-based-component

while using react classcomponent , I am not able to set the states in the states section,I am trying to set a number and an array from API, I am not able to set both , the number is also showing undefined.

There is no error in the api as well, if I try to console.log it, it works well.
Please help me in this issue.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import RSSParser from "rss-parser";

class BlogFeed extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      number: 0,
      items:[],
      feed:[]
    };
    this.makeTimer();
  }

  makeTimer() {
    setInterval(() => {
      let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
      this.setState({ number: rand });
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentDidMount = () =>{
    let parser = new RSSParser();
    parser.parseURL(`https://7targets.ai/blog/feed.xml`, function (err, feed) {
      if (err) throw err;
      this.setState({items : feed.items});
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.items)
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Random Number :{this.state.items[this.state.number]}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default BlogFeed;
```

Comment: `setInterval` should be called from `componentDidMount` & the corresponding `clearInterval` from `componentWillUnmount`.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing arrow functions and regular functions.

Fix it in `componentDidMount`:

```
 componentDidMount = () =>{
    let parser = new RSSParser();
    parser.parseURL(`https://7targets.ai/blog/feed.xml`, (err, feed) => {
                                                      // ^---turn it into arrow fn
      if (err) throw err;
      this.setState({items : feed.items});
    });
  }
```

Comment: Arrow functions don't *auto-define* their *own* `this`. They use the `this` of their parent context. In this case, it's the current object/component instance.